# How to render emojis in matplotlib with 'natural' colors?

Tags: python, matplotlib, emoji

I want to use emoji in a plot, which works with the correct font (*Segoe UI Emoji* on Windows), however I cannot figure out how to use the 'natural' colors.  When rendered in a browser or MS Word, the glyphs have their own colors defined (I presume) by the font.  In this example, they are grey and yellow.  However they become monochrome when used in matplotlib and I can't seem to use `'auto'` as a font color.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.text(.2, .2, '', fontname='Segoe UI Emoji', fontsize=20)
ax.text(.4, .4, '', fontname='Segoe UI Emoji', fontsize=20)
ax.text(.6, .6, '', fontname='Segoe UI Emoji', fontsize=20)
ax.text(.8, .8, '', fontname='Segoe UI Emoji', fontsize=20)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Don't know if you'll find useful info here: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12830

Comment: @PeterConstable Yes, that information was posted previously but that user seems to have deleted his answer.  I attempted the mplcairo fix but it doesn't seem to work on Windows.  It isn't clear to me if the QT module is essential to the fix, but I couldn't get it to work.  The Tk module and the Base module produced wildly incorrect results.

Answer (score 1):

i have created a small library (imojify) to deal with colored emoji issue

```
from imojify import imojify
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage,AnnotationBbox

def offset_image(cords, emoji, ax):

    img = plt.imread(imojify.get_img_path(emoji))
    im = OffsetImage(img, zoom=0.08)
    im.image.axes = ax
    ab = AnnotationBbox(im, (cords[0], cords[1]),  frameon=False, pad=0)
    ax.add_artist(ab)


emjis = ['', '', '', '']
pos =[0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))

for i, e in enumerate(emjis):
    offset_image([pos[i],pos[i]], e, ax)
```

the library contains images for all emojis,
`imojify.get_img_path(emoji)` simply returns the path of the emoji image then you can use OffsetImage to add these images as labels, text, or whatever you want